# Get Android Updated Application

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have been searching around this site and google for a couple of hours now, and I can't find anything about this. Maybe because I use the wrong search terms, I don't know.

I am making an Application List for an App of mine, and for the most part this is easy enough. My problem is that when I come across an updated system application, I need to get information about the original package file (The one in /system/app rather than the updated one in /data/app), information like version and file name.

Now, I could extract this as root from /data/system/packages.xml, but I thought that there might be a better native solution using PackageManager like with the rest of the application list?